# Why is touchstart event after click?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, webkit, touch

Here's something odd, that I felt sure was working in earlier mobile browsers: In Chrome on Android, and Safari on iOS, it seems the touchstart event is fired *after* the click event, not before. When did this change?

A simple example:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var touched = false;
    $('#clicky').on('touchstart', function(evt){
        touched = true;
        evt.preventDefault();
    })
    .click(function(){
        if (!touched) {
            alert("somehow touch didn't fire")
        }
    });
})
```

Run this fiddle, and you'll see the alert can pop up on Android and iOS, when it should actually never show!

http://jsfiddle.net/quxnxu7d/2/

Comment: In the touch emulation in Firefox (dev tools → mobile view → emulate touch events) it works as expected.

Comment: @Xufox So it's yet-another-webkit-bug? I wouldn't be surprised...

Comment: Not so sure about that… I haven’t tested it on Firefox for Android or on Firefox OS, etc.

Comment: can't repro on chrome 43 on Android 4.4 (CM11) neither on FF38, neither on Safari on an ipad mini (ios 8.3)

Comment: @Kaiido Can u try again, it does happen sometimes - not sure why

Comment: Ok , with this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/quxnxu7d/12/ I'm only able to get "didn't worked" when I do click between the div and the "log" text. Otherwise, it always do work. (Only tested from my phone though, FF & chrome) and when `touchstart` fires, it's always before `click`

Comment: In which versions of OS/browsers did you tested it?

Comment: @SergeyDenisov I think it was Android 4.4, & iOS 8.3

Comment: @NoBugs works as expected on iPad Mini 3 (iOS 8.3) and iPhone 5s (iOS 8.3) — http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/default.html.

Comment: @SergeyDenisov Yes but it is possible for touchstart to not cancel click event - why?

Comment: @NoBugs I don't know how it can be possible.

Comment: @NoBugs I can't reproduce this bug you described as well. Did you actually check your devices using the fiddle you provided? If you did and were able to reproduce this, please state the device, OS and browser.

Comment: @light Yes I did, I didn't try on simulator

Comment: So... you encountered the bug on the fiddle using actual devices, but you aren't very sure of what device / OS / browser you were using? Sounds weird to me. Adding the fact that so far nobody could reproduce the alleged bug, I'd say this question is not valid/complete.

Answer (score 7):

I ran it through Chrome on Android and it worked as you expected for me.  I added an alert to the `touchstart` handler and it fired to be sure that it was firing first and it did.

Take a look at the [touch events mdn article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events#Additional_tips). The article specifically mentions:

> calling preventDefault() on a `touchstart` or the first `touchmove` event of a series prevents the corresponding mouse events from firing

[`Click` is a mouse event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) so it "should" work as you expect (and it was working for me). I'd verify that the events are indeed running out of order (use `console.log()` instead of `alert()`) on your target browsers. If they are, which is perfectly possible with less than perfect browsers/specs, try using a different mouse event like `mouseup`. My guess is that you'll be able to find an event that works consistently.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using `mousedown` instead of `click`? That way you should get different events for touch and click without any double firing. You will also likely need to use `keydown` to keep this site accessible.

Answer (score 1):

There is a 300ms delay between a physical tap and the firing of a click event on some mobile browsers (e.g. iOS Safari)
I ran into the same issue and FastClick jQuery plugin fixed it for me

Have a look [FastClick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick)